# Difference between admin and user admin

Tags: wp-admin

What is the difference bewteen the **Admin** and **User Admin** concepts?

You can find them in different places, like:

- [_user_admin_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/_user_admin_menu/) or [is_user_admin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_admin/)
- [_admin_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/_admin_menu/) or [is_admin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/)

I did not find a clear explanation for them, and each explanation for itself does not make it clear neither. The documentation says:

**is_user_admin()**

> Whether the current request is for a user **admin screen**.

**is_admin()**

> Whether the current request is for an **administrative interface page**.

Since *admin screen* and *administrative interface page* are quite similar concepts to me, I am confused.

Also, running `is_user_admin()` in "a page in wp-admin for managing users", like '/wp-admin/users.php' returns false. Also the docs mention an example URL '/wp-admin/user/' but when I try to access this URL logged in as administrator, I get redirected to the /wp-admin/ dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

A "user admin screen" (or interface page) is a page in wp-admin for managing users. An "admin screen" (or interface page) is any page in wp-admin, which includes user admin screens but also screens for managing other types of data.

Comment: Running `is_user_admin()` in  "a page in wp-admin for managing users", like '/wp-admin/users.php' returns false.  Also the docs mention an example URL '/wp-admin/user/' but when I try to access this URL logged in as administrator, I get redirected to the /wp-admin/ dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

The user admin at `/wp-admin/user/` is the place on a multisite where a user can edit his/her profile if he/she is not assigned to any blog.

The redirect to `/wp-admin/` is very likely because you're on a single site install.